# Can we create std::type_index in TypeScript?

Tags: c++, typescript, types, typescript-generics

In C++ there is a nice [std::type_index](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index), which converts types to a value that can be stored in a map or for equality testing or similar things, like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::vector<void *>> instances;

class A { /* stuff... */ };
class B { /* stuff... */ };

template <typename Type>
void insert(Type *type) {
    type_names[std::type_index(typeid(Type))].push_back(&type);
}

insert<A>(new A());
insert<B>(new B());
```

Is there any way to do the same thing in TypeScript? A possible solution might look like this:

```
const instances: Record<string, any[]> = {};

function insert<T>(inst: T): T {
    const tid: string = ???;
    if (!instances[tid]) {
        instances[tid] = [];
    }
    instances[tid].push(inst);
}
```

In a more formal sense, I'd like a function `type_index<T>(): string` such that `type_index<A>() === type_index<B>()` if and only if the types A and B are equal

Comment: TS's type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when code is compiled, and it's a [non-goal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) of TypeScript to emit any JS that differs based on results of the type system. I find it's more helpful to frame questions like this as "How would I write this in pure JS and then how could I give that code types in TS to improve safety?" So you need to think about what runtime code would give you the string you want. Is it possible with as-is JS? Can you build it?

Comment: Also note that the TS type system is [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing), not nominal.  So the types `A` and `B` where `class A {x: string}` and `class B {x: string}` are equal according to the compiler but at runtime `new B() instanceof A` will be `false`.

Comment: Hmm that's very interesting. I agree; a pure JS solution might be a good starting point.